# wget not completely processing the http call

Tags: html, wget, radiobuttonlist

Here is a wget command that executes a HTML / PHP stack report suite that is hosted by a third party - we don't have control over the PHP or HTML page

wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=/myacc --http-password=mypass -O /tmp/myoutput.csv "https://myserver.mydomain.com/mymodule.php?myrepcode=9999&action=exportcsv&admin=myappuserid&password=myappuserpass&startdate=2011-01-16&enddate=2011-01-16&reportby=mypreferredview"

All the elements are working perfectly:

--http-user / --http-pass   as offered by a browsers standard popup for username and password prompt
-O /tmp/myoutput.csv - the output file of interest

https://myserver.mydomain.com/mymodule.php?myrepcode=9999&action=exportcsv&admin=myappuserid&password=myappuserpass&startdate=2011-01-16&enddate=2011-01-16&reportby=mypreferredview"

The file generated on the fly by the parameters

myrepcode=9999 - a reference to the report in question
action=exportcsv       internally written in the function
admin=myappuserid      the third party operats SSL to access the site - then internal username and password stored in  a database to access the functions of the site)
password=myappuserpass
startdate=2011-01-16    this and end data are parameters specific to the report 9999
enddate=2011-01-16
reportby=mypreferredview   This is an option in the report that facilitates different levels of detail or aggregation

The problem is that the reportby parameter is a radio button selection in a list of 5 selections (sure I enough the default is highest level of aggregation , I want the last one which is the most detailed)

Here is a sample of the HTML page code for the options of reportby

The tags in the HTML are not whitelisted - so I will send the sample if requested

```
<td>View by</td>
<td>
   <input class="naf-radio" name="reportby" id="reportby[thedefault]" value="thedefault" type="radio">The Default                    
   <input class="naf-radio" name="reportby" id="reportby[myleastpreferred]" value="myleastpreferred" type="radio">My Least Preferred
   <input class="naf-radio" name="reportby" id="reportby[mysecondleastpreferred]" value="mysecondleastpreferred" type="radio">My Second Least Preferred
   <input class="naf-radio" name="reportby" id="reportby[mythirdleastpreferred]" value="mythirdleastpreferred" type="radio">My Third Least Preferred
   <input class="naf-radio" name="reportby" id="reportby[mypreferred]" value="mypreferred" type="radio">My Preferred
</td>
```

No matter which of the reportby items I select in the wget statement - thedefault is always executed.

Questions

1) Has anyone come across this notation in HTML (id=inputname[inputelement]) 
I spoke to a senior web developer and he has never seen this notation for inputs (id=inputname[inputelement]) - and w3schools do not appear familiar with this either based on an extensive search

2) Can a wget command select a none default radio item when executing the command ?

This probably will be initially received with a "Use CURL" response- however the wget approach works very well in the limited environment I am operating in - particularly as I need to download 10000 of these such items.

Thanks ahead of response

Answer (score 0):

A radio button is just another form element and can be passed through the querystring usually. Some applications will demand that parameters are passed as POST data but this isn't that common in my experience.

What you'll need to do is find the name of the radio buttonand the value that is on the desired option. You then just add `&name=value` to your current url and it should act like selecting that radio button.

The notation `id=inputname[inputelement]` could exist in javascript or similar languages but not in HTML. In HTML its just name=value type of declarations in urls (and attribtues and other things). In this case I would assume that this string was meant to have been interpreted in whatever code generated the HTML rather than rendered to screen.

Also you need to make sure you urlencode any values that you are putting in the url to make sure they don't contain any illegal characters (eg an & or = will confuse it completely).

If the querystring method doesn't work then wget has a `--post-data` switch that allows you to specify data to be posted whcih is what a form would do. If you use `--post-data=reportby=mypreferred` I hope you should have more success with that.

If this still fails then I would use some tool to view your wget request as well as your request through a browser and compare the headers and data to see what is different about them. one such tool for this is fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) though I'm sure many others exist.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris - but I think there is something strange with this ...  regarding " ... You then just add &name=value to your current url and it should act like selecting that dropdown option.  "  This is precisely what we have done but as mentioned it is ignoring the call &reportby=mypreferredview   ...  These tags elements are inside an HTML td tag set - so this conflicts -  with the not in JAVA statement - your input is appreciated

Comment: correction : with the not in JAVA statement should have read - could exist in javascript but not in HTML.  - as mentioned the HTML Tags td contain id=inputname[inputelement] clauses

Comment: I've onyl just found the HTML in your question (you need to use the code formatting to mark it as code, otherwise it will treat it as HTML rather than stuff you want to display) You should be able to add `&reportby=mypreferred` onto the end of your url to do it. When working out the form data that is submitted the id isn't used, just the name and the value. I'd guess that this id syntax is a mistake and that should have been interpreted to an id before it got rendered to HTML.

Comment: I'm guessing now that the server isn't allowing that to be specified in the url, only in post data. you could try --post-data=reportby=mypreferred and see if it likes that any better (will update my answer with this too).

Comment: Chris - --postdata= - perfect ! Thanks very much - got me out of a massive hole

Comment: So in summary - not all form class input fields are processed the same when using wget (and possible). some can be processed directly in the http link - others need to be collected via the --postdata=

Comment: Yup. And this isn't jsut via wget. Its a general HTTP thing that on the server the values in the url and post data go into different collections. Usually when people look for form elements they look in both but sometimes they look in just one.

Comment: @delbyDev: And don't forget you can (and should if you are happy with it) mark my answer as correct. This is good practice and if you ask too many questions without doing this people will get grumpy with you. ;-)